# How do I resolve the $digest is already in progress while using $http in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new to Angular, and I have been following an online tutorial that is quite outdated (couldn't find a better one for my purpose), so I making changes as necessary. Here is the code of my file:-

```
(function (angular) {

    var theModule = angular.module("notesView", []);

    theModule.controller("notesViewController", 
        ["$scope", "$window", "$http",
        function ($scope, $window, $http) {
            $scope.notes = [];

            var urlParts = $window.location.pathname.split("/");
            var categoryName = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

            var notesUrl = "/api/notes/" + categoryName;

            $http.get(notesUrl)
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.notes = result.data;
            }, function (err) { 
                alert(err);
            });
        }
    ]);

})(window.angular);
```

Now when I try to run this and debug with Firebug, I get the infamous '$digest is already in progress' error. I'm sure that it has something to do with the $http.get call, because removing that section does not throw this error anymore. I also know that it can be resolved using $timeout, but I don't know how.

Please help me out. I can provide any further info, if required.

Comment: The code you posted alone **cannot** cause the error you have. It's something else you are not showing here.

Comment: somwhere in you't code you call '$apply', can you post it?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio, and I searched the entire solution for $apply, but couldn't find it. I don't remember using it anywhere. This is one of the reasons I was stumped. Every solution to this issue on the internet mentioned $apply. Since I never used that, I just posted this as  anew question.

Comment: are you changing `$scope.notes` somewhere else in your code?  unless you are using an older release of angular which might have exhibited some bug, this code isn't what is generating your error.